# What causes puberty to begin?

Tags: endocrinology

I understand that puberty begins when hormones are released from the pituitary gland as instructed by the hypothalamus, but why does the hypothalamus instruct this to occur?

How is this process timed by the body?

Comment: Too broad, sorry.

Comment: partial answer: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/3609/460

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are long time periods measured in biological systems?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/how-are-long-time-periods-measured-in-biological-systems)